# Writing the requirements/setup file for a Python package

Tags: python, python-packaging, requirements.txt

Are there any best practices on how to select the versions of the required packages for your own python package?

You can always do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, but this will set every used package to a specific version.

If this package is used with another one using the same requirement with a different specific version, you will have a problem when anaconda, pip-tools, or poetry try to find the right combination of dependencies.

To let your package work with others, the best would be to let the version selected be as wide as possible, for example `numpy>=1.20,<1.21`.

Is there a good way to do this for the entire set of requirements of a package?

Comment: This kind of question is somewhat out of scope for StackOverflow. Everyone will have their opinion. -- Maybe you should read [_setup.py vs requirements.txt](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/). -- The first question is: are we talking about a library or an application? Because those 2 cases lead to very different considerations.

Comment: In this case to a library (package), but it would apply to any pair of pieces of python software that will coexist in the same environment. Thank you for the link, it is an interesting one. However, I still have no clue how to achieve a library that won't make it impossible to include it in an environment because of its tight dependencies.

Comment: My advice: for each direct dependency, ***only exclude the versions for which you are 100% sure that they are incompatible with your library***, and that's pretty much it. For example if we work on a library `MyLib` that depends on `SomeLib` whose current version is `2.3.1`, we could think it is wise to exclude version 3 because we could assume that `SomeLib 3` will be incompatible; I would strongly recommend against it, because we can not predict the future and it might actually turn out to be compatible.

Comment: _(to continue on my previous example)_ -- On the other hand, if it turns out that the newly realeased `SomeLib 3` is incompatible with our own `MyLib`, then my recommendation would be to release "post builds" of each branch we are still maintaining to address this incompatibility, so for example we would release `MyLib 1.post1` where `SomeLib 3` is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

In the packaging metadata of your library (in other words: in the `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, or `pyproject.toml`), only the direct dependencies should be listed. The direct dependencies are the ones that are directly imported by the library's code (and the ones that are called in sub-processes, but that is quite a rare case). Since no one can predict the future, my advice regarding version constraints on the dependencies is to ***only exclude the versions (or version ranges) for which you are 100% sure that they are incompatible with your library***.

For example, we are working on `MyLib v9` and want to add a dependency on `SomeLib` which has only `v1` and `v2` available. The features of `SomeLib` that we want are not available in `v1` but they are on `v2`. We do not know if those features will still be there in `SomeLib v3+` or not, since we can not predict the future. So in the packaging metadata of our `MyLib v9`, we should declare dependency `SomeLib>=2` (or `SomeLib!=1`).

Some months later `SomeLib v3` and then `SomeLib v4` are released, and they are indeed compatible with  our library. We do not need to do anything, whoever installs our `MyLib` will automatically get the latest version of `SomeLib`, which is `v4` and is compatible.

Some more months later, `SomeLib v5` is released and it is not compatible with our library. So we should release `MyLib v9.post1` where we adjust the dependency specification in packaging metadata with `SomeLib>=2,<5` (or `SomeLib!=1,!=5`).

If when the incompatible `SomeLib v5` is released, we have all abandoned the maintenance of our `MyLib` and do not release the post-build, then users of our `MyLib` are still able to manually exclude the problematic `SomeLib v5` from dependency resolution (for example with [a *pip* `constraints.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files)). This is well supported in the Python packaging ecosystem, very easy to do.

On the other hand, if right from the start we had eagerly excluded everything but `SomeLib v2` in our initial `MyLib v9` release (maybe with a dependency specification such as `SomeLib==2`), and then immediately abandoned the maintenance of the library, then no one would have been able to install our `MyLib v9` with `SomeLib v3` (or `v4`), even though it is a perfectly valid combination. This eager over-specification of exclusions is the cause of a lot of (unsolvable) issues, a near dead-end, this should really be avoided.

That is why, from my point of view, the only thing dependency version constraints should do is exclude well-known (and proven) incompatibilities. Then, as much as possible, publish "post build" releases to improve the version constraints as new incompatibilities appear.

***References***

- https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/
- https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#post-release-separators
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files